# [u"'0' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Tags: python, django, date

I have a datefield.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  today = models.DateField()
  ..
```

User saves his object. if today is given, then fine. if not, i need to set `today` Field to some value so that i can know later that user didnot set the date. I dont want to make it nullable.

so I set it to `0`, but while saving, it is saying the error which i put as title.

before saving i am doing this:

```
if today and today.strip():
    pass
else:
    today = 0
```

what default value can i else set?

Comment: Why don't you want to make it nullable?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi because i am sorting objects by this field, if is null, then it doesnot show up in sort result?!

Comment: AS dateField, don't you think you should give a date? how about datetime.datetime().today().date() or whatever date you pick

Comment: @JerryMeng, the problem with this is that if user intentionally doesnot set the date, then if i do *datetime.datetime().today().date()*, then it is against user's will

Comment: I know. so pick a date you think will make it more sense, rather than 0. My point is give a value with valid type. and in this case, that type should be datetime.date rather than int

Comment: @JerryMeng yeah. this is only option, so i need to pick some never-to-come date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it to a never date. Basically a date that will never occur, for example:

`today = '9999-12-31'`

Comment: It's a bit pessimistic to suggest this date will never occur.

Comment: haha but who knows, hopefully this date will come, but by 9999 django will sure have better solution for this, so i go for it :P